# Fraction of space bounded by 3 planes

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

How can I work out the fraction of 3D space which is bounded by the following planes ?
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}x+y-z<0
\\ x-y+z<0
\\ x+y+z>0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Is there a method which extends to hyperplanes in N-dimensional space ?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/979/algorithm-for-finding-the-volume-of-a-convex-polytope

Comment: It's called an octant, because the three planes divide space into $8$ regions.  (There are $8$ possible combinations of plus and minus signs.)  I would called that a numerical fraction of space, though.  In $n-$space, $n$ generally-positioned hyperplanes divide space into $s^n$ regions, for the same reason.